# Why is ClearType partially not working with transparent Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, transparency

I have a transparent `Window` which works fine, but a `TextBox` ignores the `ClearType`.

The `RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"` is set but nothing happens. There is no other Effect, OpacityMask, VisualBrush, DrawingBrush, Clip, or Opacity only `AllowsTransparency="True"` and `AllowsTransparency="True"`.

#### AllowsTransparency="True"

[image]

#### AllowsTransparency="False" on normal Window

[image]

#### Xaml sample

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="200"
        Width="300"
        Title="MainWindow"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStyle="None">

  <Window.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>

      <Grid Background="White"
            Height="200"
            Width="300"
            RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
            TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
            TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">

        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
          <Label>Lorem Ipsum Test</Label>
          <TextBlock>Lorem Ipsum Test</TextBlock>
          <TextBox Text="Lorem Ipsum"
                   Background="White" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Template>

</Window>
```

Any suggestions? Is this a known issue that can not be solved?

**UPDATE**

With `Snoop` I see a `TextBoxLineDrawingVisual`, maybe this is causing the issue?

[image]

Comment: ClearType text does not display correctly on a background that is not fully opaque. Intermediate render targets, such as Effect, OpacityMask, VisualBrush, DrawingBrush, Clip, and Opacity, can introduce backgrounds that are not fully opaque. WPF disables ClearType when it detects that the buffer into which text is drawn could have a transparent background. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.cleartypehint(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr I know this, but the `TextBox` has a normal `Background`. And by the way, why works the `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 0):

That's because grid's attached properties for text like "RenderingMode" internally implemented to apply on "textblock" not "textbox" child elements.